# Implementing VOIP with Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, voip

I currently have a app created using PhoneGap running solely on IOS, with future plans of possible providing multi-platform functionality. I am trying to implement a VOIP feature (like a Walkie Talkie) into my app solely over an internal network. I tried exploring Phono but to no avail as it requires me to be connected to the internet. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is to implement your VOIP functionality in native and then make a custom plugin for PhoneGap so your HTML5 app can communicate with the Native code.

You can use Twilio Client if you don't want to write everything yourself.They have API for both iOS and Android

http://www.twilio.com/client/mobile

To make a custom plugin for PhoneGap take a look at:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

---

The other option is to use WEBRTC:

http://www.webrtc.org/